# SQL with multiple select statements for distinct entities

Tags: sql

I am trying to learn some SQL and what I want to do is simply select some rows from a table according to some criteria.

So, I am trying something like:

```
Select * from mytable where id=1090 as A, Select * from mytable where id=1075 as B;
```

I need to keep them as distinct entities (A and B) in my example, so that I can do something like:

```
Select A.col, B.row from A, B where <some criteria>
```

I am unable to figure out how to put all this together in a SQL query

Comment: `Select * from mytable where id in(1090, 1075)`

Comment: Are those select return 1 row each?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri No, can return multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this magic to achieve what you want, if I understand you correctly. This will return rows side by side, don't know how to explain:

```
;with a as(select *, row_number() over(order by(select null)) rn 
           from tableA where id = 1090),
      b as(select *, row_number() over(order by(select null)) rn 
           from tableB where id = 1075)
select a.*, b.*
from a 
full join b on a.rn = b.rn
```

If first select returns 4 rows and second 2 rows the output will be something like:

```
A(rn, cols)   B(rn, cols)
1 .........   1 .........
2 .........   2 .........
3 .........   NULL
4 .........   NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select A.*, B.*
from
    (Select * from mytable where id=1090) as A
join
    (Select * from mytable where id=1075) as B ON <some criteria>
```